# How to insert image into remote database by iOS app?

Tags: php, ios

In my iOS app, I have to store image in remote database. I have done it by BLOB already.But I want to do it by storing its path only. I have tried it a lot but I am failing to write client side code.

**Client side code:**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgview.image,0.2);     //change Image to NSData

if (imageData != nil)
{
    NSString *filenames = @"catttt.jpeg";      //set name here
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/insertIntoImage.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpeg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
    NSLog(@"finish");
}
```

**Remote side code:**

```
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['filenames']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['filenames']) . " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add some code what u have done?

Comment: If you are failing to write  client side code then you must learn Swift or Objective C first! So that you can make an attempt to write code .

Comment: tell what you have tried, and what you want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First upload image to server and then update image name/path to DB

Below is function to store image to Server

Here $image is a imagedata comes from IOS APP

```
$image = $_POST['image_name_from_app'];
$image = str_replace("<", "", $image);
$image = str_replace(">", "", $image);
$image = str_replace("&lt;", "", $image);
$image = str_replace("&gt;", "", $image);
$image = preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/', '', $image);
$bin = hex2bin($image);
$path = "user_images/";
$imageName = time() .".png";
$path = "user_images/";
if (file_put_contents($path . $imageName, $bin)) {
  return $imageName;
}
return false;
```